# @How to convert strings to integers on a split in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I am reading in lines from a data file one at a time, splitting them on **:** and trying to store two specific values from the array into a hash.

```
foreach $a (<INPUT>)
{   

    @list = split (':', $a);

    $UIDH{$list[2]} = $list[5];
```

Then I try to compare the value stored in the hash.

```
if (($list[2]) < 500 && > 0);
        {
            print "System type account\n";
        }
```

That is the if I'm using. My conclusion is that the value in the hash is a string so the comparison isn't working. Below is my code as it appears in the program.

```
open (INPUT, "<info.old") || die "Cannot open file : $!";
open (OUTPUT, ">out.txt") || die "Cannot open file : $!";

%UIDH;

foreach $a (<INPUT>)
{   

    @list = split (':', $a);

    $UIDH{$list[2]} = $list[6];

    if (($list[2]) >= 500)
        {
            print STDOUT "R\n";
        }
    if (($list[2]) < 500 && > 0);
        {
            print STDOUT "S\n";
        }
    if (($list[2]) == 0)
        {
            print STDOUT "SU\n";
        }

}
```

Lastly, here is an example of the data I'm working with

```
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
msmith:x:501:501::/home/msmith:/bin/bash
Sjones:x:502:502::/home/sjones:/bin/bash
sdonle:x:503:503::/home/sdavis:/bin/sh
scrosby:x:504:504::/home/scrosby:/bin/bash
borr:x:0:0::/home/borr:/bin/sh
```

Comment: `if (($list[2]) < 500 && > 0);` is a syntax error. Can you please copy and paste the exact code you're using? (or better yet, create a [mcve])

Comment: I edited it and added the missing line (%UIDH;) other than my closes that is my code

Comment: Why in the first listing you have `$UIDH{$list[2]} = $list[5];` and in the second `$UIDH{$list[2]} = $list[6];` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you claim the comparison isn't working when you never got to evaluate it because your code doesn't even compile.

```
if (($list[2]) < 500 && > 0); { ... }
```

should be

```
if (($list[2]) < 500 && $list[2] > 0) { ... }
```

Two errors:

- `>` is a binary operator; it needs to be used between two expressions to compare.
- The format of an `if` statement is `if (EXPR) BLOCK`, but you had `if (EXPR); BLOCK`.

With these errors fixed, your code outputs the following:

```
S
R
R
R
R
SU
```

This appears to be the expected result, but you didn't state what you were expecting.

Note: You would greatly benefit from having your code [reviewed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

To make your code more readable and easier to maintain, you should use meaningful names for your variables.

```
@list = split (':', $a);
my $account_number = $list[2];
my $account_uidh   = $list[5];
```